# Property 'sort' is used before its initialization

Tags: angular

[image]

```
Property 'sort' is used before its initialization.ts(2729)
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: `public sort: SortDescriptor[];` defines a _type_ for that property, but no _value_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public sort: SordDescriptior[] = null;` or  `public sort: SordDescriptior[] = [];`